# Specifying named parameter

Tags: c#, arguments, optional-arguments

I have a function with the following signature

```
public static void raiseEventtoForm(string message, Color fc, Color bc, int messageType, 
    EventLogEntryType eventType = EventLogEntryType.Information, bool frmSQL = false)
    {
        if(eventType != EventLogEntryType.Information && !frmSQL)
            postEventLog(message, eventType);
        MessageEvent(message, fc, bc, frmSQL);
    }
```

But when I try to call it and set it I am getting an invalid argument pass, I've tried the following ways. What am I doing wrong?

```
ProgramEvents.raiseEventtoFrom("example", Color.Black, Color.White, frmSQL:true);
ProgramEvents.raiseEventtoFrom("example", Color.Black, Color.White, frmSQL:= true);
```

Edit:
Error: No overload takes 4 arguments

*This was a /facepalm situation where I missed the glaringly obvious

Comment: Please post exact error message. Most likely it complains about not passing required arguments like `message`.

Comment: Since this was a dumb, not-seeing-the-obvious-issue should I delete it or leave it?

Comment: I don't know - you have answer - so feel free to keep it. If you decide to keep - make question better by adding error message and formatting code to avoid horizontal scroll. Make sure to add error code (like CSxxxx) along with message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't specify the fourth required argument: `int messageType`

Comment: Thank you- that was it- can't beleive I missed that- I'll mark in 6 mins when I'm allowed

Answer (score 3):

`int messafeType` is not an optional parameter (does not have a default set) so it is not a valid method call

Answer (score 2):

You can only leave out parameters which have default values specified. 
But you left `messageType` parameter for which there wasn't any default value, which is why you got error.